# Create a second "virtualized" mouse

Tags: java, c#, windows, mouseevent

I was asking myself, if I could automatize a workflow that needs a cursor (+ left clicks).
So I just went to do that..
Long story short: As I use that program, I can't use my pc because the mouse is busy with the given workflow.

Is there a way to create a second "virtualized mouse" that gets handled by the automatic workflow while the user can use his mouse like always?

Do you have any ideas or maybe experience?

I know, that a VM could finish all my problems - but this is too easy!

Thanks in advice! :)

Comment: Instead of going through the trouble of creating a second cursor (which is ridiculous) you should create an application to perform the workflow automatically without user interaction.

Comment: @DanWilson thanks for your answer. I guess you mean accessing via memory?

Comment: I mean writing an application or script to do the work you want.